# I switched breaker boxes on my house but when I started turning on lights the bulbs blew and surge protectors fried

Tags: electrical, lighting, electrical-panel

I changed my electrical breaker box. When I turned lights on the bulbs blew and the surge protector sparked and shut off. The only thing I could figure is the ground line to the ground from the box isn't connected.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Sometimes the right move is to recognize when you shouldn't DIY something you don't understand, without first understanding it, and if that proves too much, just...don't. Pretty sure this isn't your cup of DIY.  I really can't see trying to get to the bottom of your problem if you think it's remotely OK to power up a breaker box with no ground attached.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more information and pictures, but if bulbs are blowing it sounds like you may have wired 240 volts to 120 volt circuits - don't turn anything else on until you get it sorted out.

Comment: Hopefully you last long enough to read this...Get a electrician

Comment: This sounds like you screwed up the service neutral connection :/

Comment: reminds me when they wired a 208v shore receptacle into the 480v panel at work

Answer (score 4):

Except in an emergency situation, ground not connected would probably not cause a lot of problems. It is *important* but not a direct cause of problems most of the time.

However, there are a *lot* of other things that could cause problems. The most obvious that come to mind are:

- Feed Wires Crossed

Specifically, one of the hots and the neutral swapped. Main panel feed wires vary a bit, particularly depending on whether it is a true main panel or the true main panel is next to the meter (meter main) and the inside breaker panel is actually a subpanel. With a traditional main panel, the ground is defined *in* the main panel, so the feed is two hots and neutral, and often that neutral is bare. But if the inside panel is actually a subpanel then it gets two hots and a neutral and a ground. The key being that the hots and neutral are **big** wires and, as a result, they often only come in black. Which means it is on the installer to make sure they are installed correctly. Install them incorrectly and you'll get hot-to-neutral on one side of 240V (because it is really hot-hot) and on the other side 120V and normally 240V circuits (water heater, oven, etc.) will have 120V. **And things will go boom!**.

- Lost Neutral

In this situation, neutral doesn't stick to the middle. Instead of 120V + 120V = 240V, you might get 100V + 140V = 240V or 160V + 80V = 240V, etc. And it will keep changing as loads are added/removed from the system, resulting in a lot of strange stuff and potential damage.

- Miswired Breakers

This *should* be very unusual, as it *should* be really obvious that black and red wires go to the main breaker connections and white wires go to the neutral bar. But there are exceptions to even those rules (e.g., black/white cable used for a 240V double-breaker for a water heater) so anything could happen.

The bottom line is that something *very serious and dangerous* is going on. Which is not a good thing. Pictures are a must. A CAT III multimeter would be helpful. A torque driver. And very likely hiring a competent licensed electrician.

Changing switches and receptacles is in easy reach of any cautious DIY. Breaker box replacement requires some real skills and attention to detail.

Comment: Neophytes often call neutral the "ground". Not connecting "ground" (neutral) is equivalent to a lost neutral, which you mentioned, and which accounts for the blown out bulbs and surge protectors.

Comment: I got the correct way to connect the white wire to the right side of the panel